# Android permission only for certain cases

Tags: android, permissions, geolocation, usability

I want to use geolocation in my app only for users from a certain country, in order to find out the country (the language on the device doesn't have this country).

My app doesn't use geolocation for anything else and I don't want to bother the rest of the users / world asking for geolocation permission.

Is there a way to solve this? The only thing I can think about, is skip asking for the permission and put the code accessing geolocation in try - catch block, but this obviously will not get the geolocation in many cases (although I have a fallback strategy for this).

There is a fallback strategy, the app will not stop working if I don't get the geolocation. But it's nice if I can get it, and it's also nice if I don't bother users of other countries with geolocation permission.

Any suggestion, advice? Thanks.

Comment: As I know, you are able to choose permisions for whole application. But you can create two applications. But you can't use [multiple apk suppport](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#SingleAPK)

Comment: Yes, I cannot use multiple apk support because this is country specific and that doesn't seem to be supported.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are better off making two versions of your application, and then use the Google Play publishers' console to provision one version to the specific countries you are concerned about, and the other for everyone else.  In this case, I'd go ahead and just let it be two different apps, two different package names, etc.

Comment: Uhm... well, but this leads me to other question. How does google play know where the user is, in order to show the correct version?

Comment: It's related with a thought about, that if the user happens to be in this country at the point of time downloading the app, he will never get rid of this country specific setting, unless he removes and reinstalls the (other) app and this is also not nice...

Comment: Most of the important geolocation logic in the Google Play Store is server-based, where it has access to a lot of additional resources that may not be available to a mobile device.

Comment: Well, yes, you need a Google Account to use Google Play, so there's a lot more information available.

Comment: Oh, sorry... I assumed you had a regulatory/distribution problem, which I would expect to be relevant at install time more than runtime.

Comment: No, it's a setting which will determine behaviour at runtime. But, hm, maybe I could use the setting of the specific app as the default and change it, if the device's locale changes, or similar... anyways +1, thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

This could work.

Assumptions - Access to a IPAddresstoLocation API

Use the following code to fetch the IP address of the device

```
public String getLocalIpAddress()
  {
          try {
              for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                  NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                  for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                      InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                      if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                          return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                      }
                  }
              }
          } catch (Exception ex) {
              Log.e("IP Address", ex.toString());
          }
          return null;
      }
```

With the IP Address if you have access to any API that would return the location, your issue should be resolved.

Comment: But this also requires a permission- android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE right?